# Firebase Dynamic Link Info with google-api-php-client v2.2.1

Tags: php, firebase, google-api, firebase-dynamic-links

I try to get the dynamic link information (click statistic) for a 'shortened' firebase dynamic link.

This is the source I have so far:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(DIR_APP . '/lib/Google/client_credentials.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_FirebaseDynamicLinks::FIREBASE);

$service = new Google_Service_FirebaseDynamicLinks($client);
$response = $service->v1->getLinkStats($short_url);
```

which gives me the following error:

```
cURL error 7: (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
---------------------------------
CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7)

Failed to connect() to host or proxy.
```

The $service->rootUrl is for some reasons 'https://firebasedynamiclinks-ipv6.googleapis.com/', but even if I change it to "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/" (like meantioned at 'https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/analytics') the error is still the same.

I have the feeling I am missing something very simple, can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, not directly an answer to my original question, but a solution to the problem itself.

```
$short_url      = "https://abc.app.goo.gl/12345abc";
$client         = new Google_Client();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_FirebaseDynamicLinks::FIREBASE);
$client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/credentials.json');
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();

$authorization  = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$client->getAccessToken()['access_token'];
$url            = "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/".urlencode($short_url)."/linkStats?durationDays=7";

$ch             = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,           $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: application/json' , $authorization ));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$ret = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($ret);
```

Prints out:

```
{
  "linkEventStats": [
    {
      "count": "4",
      "event": "CLICK",
      "platform": "OTHER"
    },
    {
      "count": "4",
      "event": "REDIRECT",
      "platform": "OTHER"
    }
  ]
}
```